# Systemd: service.tor started too quickly

Tags: systemd, python, python3, tor

I'm using tor service for my script but I get this error:

```
 The job identifier is 17084 and the job result is failed.
Şub 26 03:12:11 Ugroon systemd[1]: tor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Şub 26 03:12:11 Ugroon systemd[1]: tor.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit tor.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Şub 26 03:12:11 Ugroon systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

I'm using 50 threads

Pyton Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from os import system
from sys import argv
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


system("service tor start")

def times(p):
    if p%15 == 0:    
        system("service tor restart && ./test.sh " + str(p) + " " + str(argv[1]) + " " + str(argv[2]))

    else:
        system("./test.sh " + str(p) + " " + str(argv[1]) + " " + str(argv[2])) 


for i in range(1000, 10000, 1):
    ThreadPoolExecutor(50).submit(times, i)
```

Bash code:

```
curl https://www.apple.com/ --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 -H "A: $1 $2$3"
```

I tried found configuration file of the tor service but I can't. I've looked /etc/tor/torrc file and /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ directory but I can't found rate limit configuration.
I want to change my IP for every 15 seconds and send curl request with this IP but as you can see I got this error.

Also I have this files in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/:
binfmt-support.service  cron.service          networking.service      nfs-client.target  rsync.service    smartmontools.service  virtualbox-guest-utils.service
console-setup.service   ModemManager.service  NetworkManager.service  remote-fs.target   rsyslog.service  stunnel.target

Note: I've asked this on stack security, askubuntu and stackoverflow but I can not get a response

Edit:
My instance configurations:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

journalctl -xeu tor@testugroon.service output:

[image]

Comment: Service files are located in ````/usr/lib/systemd/system/```` or ````/etc/systemd/system/```` generally, you can also edit the file using ````systemctl edit <service>````(specify --full to see the file while editing) But you really shouldn't be using ````systemctl start <service>```` to change IPs. ````systemctl reload <service>```` is probably a smarter option (uses the ````ExecReload=```` directive instead of ````ExecStart=```` since reload doesn't have a limit before throwing an error like start does.

Comment: @ReedGhost, thanks for your reply but i can't saw start limit config, by the way i'm using service tor restart

Comment: Can you provide the contents of tor.service? It would normally be located in one of the two directories in my above comment. Also your tor instance is configured as a systemd service, so it is recommended you use ````systemctl```` to manage it rather than using the ````service```` command. When you use ````service tor <command>```` you are actually just being redirected to systemctl anyways.

Comment: [Unit]
Description=Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: this is my tor.service content

Comment: You should remove your comment and add the additional information to your question in a codeblock to make it easier for others to digest.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through your comments I think this more or less boils down to how you're using tor. Tor in its present implementation, is meant to be used as a multi instanced service. When you are running `service tor restart` or `service tor start`  since now tor no longer seems to provide an `init.d` script(This was new to me) you are actually just being redirected to a systemd unit file `tor.service`.

This file is meant to be a master file for instances, which in this case means it is doing nothing at all. As you  can see from

```
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
```

It simply will execute /bin/true which only has the purpose of exiting with status 0(true in shells).

What you need to do is run `tor-instance-create <instance name>`  which will create a new tor instance.

You can then interact with this service instance via

```
systemctl <stop|start|restart|reload> tor@<instance name>
```

To address the second half of  your problem, which is **why you received the error**.

systemd services cannot be restarted repeatedly without running to the service start-limit, which is what generated your error originally. This will not change when you go to use an instance.

If it is not already configured to do so, after creating your instance, you should modify `ExecReload` to accurately reflect what it is you're attempting to do(restart the service).

We do this because unlike `systemctl start tor@<instance name>` and `systemctl restart tor@<instance name>`, executing `systemctl reload tor@<instance name>` does not have a limit on the number of times you may execute it.

You can do this by executing `systemctl edit tor@<instance name> --full`. Your final result may look like the following:

```
[Unit]
# ....some preconfigured stuff...

[Service]
# ...more preconfigured stuff...
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}
# ...preconfigured stuff...

[Install]
# ...final preconfigured stuff...
```

After you've made (or not made if its not needed) the necessary changes, you should modify your script to leverage this;

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from os import system
from sys import argv
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


system("systemctl start tor@<instance name>")

def times(p):
    if p%15 == 0:    
        system("systemctl reload tor@<instance name> && ./test.sh " + str(p) + " " + str(argv[1]) + " " + str(argv[2]))

    else:
        system("./test.sh " + str(p) + " " + str(argv[1]) + " " + str(argv[2])) 


for i in range(1000, 10000, 1):
    ThreadPoolExecutor(50).submit(times, i)
```

**EDIT**:
If the `tor@<instance name>.service` configures itself as `Type=oneshot` please let me know in the comments I will adjust the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but still I get the same error. I was execute this commands: 1: tor-instance-create test 2 (for being sure about output): tor-instance-create testugroon 3: systemctl start tor@testugroon 4: edited code as what you said

Comment: I edited question and added screen shot of my instance configurations

Comment: I just tested this on my own system without any issues; What distribution/OS are you on? It looks as if your version of ````kill```` may use different syntax than what my system; and the system the package was made for uses. Which seems to be the source of the error.

Comment: But as a general measure you can replace ````ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}```` with ````ExecReload=/bin/kill -1 ${MAINPID}```` as they are equivalent in function (SIGHUP is code 1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use kali linux 2021.2

Comment: Can you try running systemctl reload tor@testugroon from terminal rather than in your script? In the event you still run into a failure, can you attempt it with the above numerical version as well.

Comment: No there is not problem when execute on terminal because of it's for just one time reloading, if I do that too fast, that will give same error. If there is no solution for that, I need send request to site with different IP's each request, how can I do that

Comment: Are you running into a limit when you run the reloads or what precisely is your error? Because the journalctl -xe output in your question right now looks like you have an issue with syntax on the ````kill```` command.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is no issue with running ````systemctl reload <service>```` as many times as one would please to. Additionally testing this on my own setup yielded no issues; So I suspect the issue lies in the fact that you are trying to use a threadpool to do this? I didn't pay much attention to that line of code initially, but I would imagine that multiple threads trying to restart this one process is probably causing unexpected functionality.